# Cron job php Unable to load dynamic library

Tags: php

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20151012/php_mysqli.dll' - /usr/lib/php/2015101
2/php_mysqli.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20151012/php_pdo_firebird.dll' - /usr/lib/php/2
0151012/php_pdo_firebird.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20151012/php_pdo_mysql.dll' - /usr/lib/php/2015
1012/php_pdo_mysql.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20151012/php_pdo_oci.dll' - /usr/lib/php/201510
12/php_pdo_oci.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20151012/php_pdo_odbc.dll' - /usr/lib/php/20151
012/php_pdo_odbc.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20151012/php_pdo_pgsql.dll' - /usr/lib/php/2015
1012/php_pdo_pgsql.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20151012/php_pdo_sqlite.dll' - /usr/lib/php/201
51012/php_pdo_sqlite.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20151012/php_pgsql.dll' - /usr/lib/php/20151012
/php_pgsql.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'PDO' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
```

I am on `Ubuntu 16.04` trying to get a cron job running correctly for an `Oxwall` site.

Answer (score 0):

I had to comment out the dll files in the php.ini file in order for it to work. Probably need some of the php extensions for it to work.